# iOS - The easiest way to integrate library that does not support SPM

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods, swift-package-manager

I use SPM in my project and want to integrate [Texture](https://github.com/TextureGroup/Texture). My project is divided into different modules using SPM. I want to use Texture only in one.

The problem is that Texture does not support SPM. What's the easies way to integrate it?

I tried to integrate it using CocoaPods but in this case I can't access it from my local package (Modules/MyLocalPackage).
However I can import Texture in my 'main project' (brushed with black).

[image]

Comment: https://github.com/TextureGroup/Texture/issues/1714 & https://github.com/TextureGroup/Texture/pull/1928 There is a "forgotten" PR? might be a good start?

Answer (score 1):

The last option for you is to download and drag it manually into your project